# Namespaced ApplicationController in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have my regular ApplicationController class & I have a Admin::ApplicationController class. The problem is that Admin::ApplicationController doesn't seem to be getting loaded or executed or anything. Am I not allowed to have a namespaced application controller? The reasoning for wanting to have it is so that I can check if a user is an admin w/ CanCan & redirect them out if they're not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call this controller `Admin::BaseController`, as it is more to act as the base of the namespace than to do anything for the appilcation. For it to do what you want to do, you will need to make all admin namespaced controllers inherit from this controller.

Comment: Hi Ryan, any chance to explain why the controller should be renamed? Just wondering, since I do have a functional Admin::ApplicationController which works just fine. Isn't that the point of namespaces?

Comment: It's not an ApplicationController though. It's the *base* for a namespace, where everywhere else inherits from. My reasons for this is mainly because it's `ActiveRecord::Base` that we inherit from in our models. Just a bit of consistency.

Comment: Thanks. In my apps the consistency is the other way around. Admin::ApplicationController inherits from ActionController::Base. For all intents and purposes /admin is a separate app inside the main app, has it's own before filtering and everything. It works quite well for me.

Answer (score 2):

The only times I've seen namespacing like that is when the controller is nested in a subfolder. So Admin::ApplicationController would expect to be in controllers/admin/application_controller.rb

One possible solution:

If you want everything except your home page to kick them out, simply set a before_filter on your application controller with an exception for home/index like this:

ApplicationController.rb

```
before_filter :authorize_admin

def authorize_admin
   //dostuff
end
```

HomeController.rb

```
skip_before_filter :authorize_admin, :only => ['index']
```

Where index is your action that you want to skip. Leave off the only to skip the filter for the whole controller.

Comment: I agree that it would be simpler to use an authorization method in a `before_filter`. Using namespaces seems like an unnecessary complication to me.